# How can I view and query data on firebase's web client?

Tags: android, parse-platform, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have used Parse in the past but I now want to move to firebase. In Parse, you can view all your data on the web as tables, and you can query that data. On Firebase, it seems all my data is stored in a giant json structure. That's fine with me. However, it seems that is also the way all my data is actually presented to me and I don't see any way to query my data. Is this a massive shortcoming of firebase or am I missing something? Say I had 100000 users in firebase, how the hell can I find that user and view that user's properties from the web client/dashboard?

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#filtering_data

Comment: I understand filtering the data in my app, but I'm wondering how I can filter the data in the web client. @FrankvanPuffelen